# Can't get data from file stored in asset catalog

Tags: ios, xcode

I am storing several .svg files in an asset catalog.
To retrieve an asset I use the following code:

```
 NSDataAsset *asset = [[NSDataAsset alloc] initWithName:@"p"];
```

When running this code I get the following log message:

> CoreUI: attempting to lookup a named data 'p' with a type that is not a data type in the AssertCatalog

The name of the file is 'p.svg' which is stored in a folder with 'dataset' as extension. I tried using other extensions for the file but nothing works. I always get the same error and the asset is nil.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to a problem I'm having, in that the UTI I'm identifying my assets as being could run up the UTI dependancies and find `public.image`, thus making CoreUI think the asset is an image type and not a data type.

SVGs inherit from `public.image`, so you will need to set the File Type to something that doesn't inherit from `public.image`. Having it be just `public.data` will suffice.

[image: what you need to change]

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the svg or whatever file in your project like .h/.m:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"p" ofType:@"svg"];
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

If path is nil, try:

```
In the Xcode target "Build Phases" add the file under "Copy Bundle Resources"".
```

Comment: I don't want to move ~100 files out of an assets catalog. According to the documentation my approach should work.

Comment: Even though you don't want to move more files, you have no reason down vote my answer. If your approach works, why you ask here? Mine works too.

Comment: I think the sentiment is that are assets is the way ahead or not, so moving files or seemingly reverting to bundles seems like past tense?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue; I wanted to provide images etc from local assets store. Dragging the files into the catalog I would fetch them like so - here a String:

```
extension NSString {
    class func string(fromAsset: String) -> String {
        guard let asset = NSDataAsset.init(name: fromAsset) else {
            return String(format: "Unable to locate asset:\n%@", fromAsset)
        }
        let data = NSData.init(data: (asset.data))
        let text = String.init(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    
        if fromAsset.hasSuffix(".md"), let html = try? Down(markdownString: text!).toHTML()
        {
            let htmlDoc = String(format: "<html><body>%@</body></html>", html)
            let data = Data(htmlDoc.utf8)
            if let attrs = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
                return attrs.string
            }
        }
        return text!
    }
}
```

the premise is they **have** to exist.  I think a per type / class extension would make retrieval simple.  Eventually a generic object extension could dispatch to the proper extension, as here, you'd have to know what it was, so the decision which to use is currently a manual one.